# Passing information to WSO2 BPMN

Tags: wso2, bpmn

i am defining a Workflow using WSO2 BPMN which will be integrated with our Application. When Instantiating a Process (from our application), i need to pass few information from our application to a BPMN Task which will be displayed in the Task screen.That information will be persisted in all the Task of the Workflow. How can i achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can do that by introducing form variables for each task (user tasks). But if it is a service task you should have to write a custom java class to read the variables and then add it to the **class name** field in **Main config** tab as a property in activiti designer. A sample custom java class to read process variables through service task can be implemented as below. As you can see in the below code, **employeeSalary** and **workingPeriod** are the two variables which can be passed from a particular process (from your application). And you can set these variables to the task variables by invoking  **execution.setVariable("variableName", value)** method.

```
    package org.wso2.bps.serviceTask;

    import java.util.Random;

    import org.activiti.engine.delegate.DelegateExecution;
    import org.activiti.engine.delegate.JavaDelegate;

    /**
     * Service task to calculate Bonus for employees
     *
     */
    public class App implements JavaDelegate {
        public void execute(DelegateExecution execution) throws Exception {
            int salary = Integer.parseInt((String) execution.getVariable("employeeSalary"));
            int numOfWorkingDays = Integer.parseInt((String) execution.getVariable("workingPeriod")); 
            Random randomGenerator = new Random();
            int value = randomGenerator.nextInt(10);
            int result = salary + (numOfWorkingDays * value);
            execution.setVariable("result", result);
        }
    }
```

Hope this resolves your issue.